Link between summing orthogonal projections and Projection Matrix $A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$
Assuming the usual inner product $\langle x, y\rangle = x^\mathsf{T} y$ on a real vector space $V$, I believe we can define the orthogonal projection $\mathbf P_W\colon V\to W$ as
$$\mathbf P_W(v) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\langle v, w_k\rangle}{\langle w_k,w_k\rangle} w_k,$$
Only if $w_k$ are an orthogonal set.
However if we put vectors $w_k$ as the columns of matrix $\mathbf A$ we can define our projection matrix as $\mathbf P_W = A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$
Question: Can we make an explicit relationship between this projection matrix and summing orthogonal projections. When $w_k$ are not orthogonal.
E.g. Is this projection matrix doing something special inside where it is essentially, performing the Gram-Schmidt process, and turning our $w_i$ vectors into an orthogonal set, and then manipulating them appropriately.
I have been able to understand the calculus reasoning as to why $(A^TA)^{-1}A^T\mathbf y$ gives us our least squares estimators of parameters $\mathbf{\beta}$ in a regression setting, but ideally i would like to find some connection between the projection matrix and summing orthogonal projections, when the columns or $A$ are not orthogonal.

When the $w_i$ are orthogonal, equivalence to the sum formula is straightforward if we go step by step.
We have that $P_W(v)=A((A^TA)^{-1}(A^Tv))$, and we can work from the inside out.
$$A^Tv=\begin{pmatrix}
\langle v,w_1 \rangle \\ 
\langle v,w_2 \rangle \\
\vdots \\
\langle v,w_n \rangle
\end{pmatrix}.$$
We have that $(A^TA)_{ij}=\langle w_i, w_j\rangle$, and so $A^TA=\operatorname{diag}(\langle w_1,w_1 \rangle,\ldots, \langle w_n,w_n \rangle)$ because of the orthogonality, and so
$$(A^TA)^{-1}=\operatorname{diag}\left(\frac{1}{\langle w_1,w_1 \rangle},\ldots, \frac{1}{\langle w_n,w_n \rangle}\right).$$
Therefore
$$(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tv=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\langle v,w_1 \rangle}{\langle w_1,w_1\rangle} \\ 
\frac{\langle v,w_2 \rangle}{\langle w_2,w_2\rangle} \\
\vdots \\
\frac{\langle v,w_n \rangle}{\langle w_n,w_n\rangle}
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Left multiplying by $A$ then gives the result.

If the $w_i$ are not orthogonal but are linearly independent (so that we can still form $P_W$), then we can still get a sum formula, but it is in terms of the singular vectors of $A$ instead of the columns of $A$.  From the singular value decomposition $A=U\Sigma V^T$, we get that $P_W=U_0U_0^T$, where $U_0$ is $U$ but with the columns corresponding to zero singular values removed.
So if the columns of $U_0$ are $u_1,\ldots,u_n$, then $P_W(v)=\sum <v,u_k>u_k$.
This then raises the question "but what is the meaning of the singular vectors?"  Unfortunately, I don't know that I have an explanation that you would find satisfactory. We are using the eigenvectors of $AA^T$ corresponding to non-zero eigenvalues, but I do not have a formula for them in terms of the $w_i$.  Without such a formula, this isn't terribly satisfying, because the same formula would work for any orthonormal basis for $W$, the this is just a particular basis that is (usually) determined by the $w_i$.
The difficulty with getting a better sum formula is that, in general, it's difficult to give the elements in $(A^TA)^{-1}$ in terms of the $w_i$.  One could use formulae for the entries of $(A^TA)^{-1}$ in terms of determinants of submatrices of $A^TA$, whose entries are of the form $\langle w_i,w_j\rangle$, but this would be complicated enough not to be so enlightening.

While not what you are asking for, perhaps a better answer would be a non-calculus reason for why $P_W$ is the projection onto $W$?
First, note that $P_WA=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^TA=A$, but if $M$ is a matrix then $M(v_1|\cdots|v_n)=(Mv_1|\cdots|Mv_n)$.  This shows that $P_W(w_i)=w_i$, and so $P_W$ acts as the identity on $W$.  On the other hand, if $v\in W^{\perp}$, then $A^Tv=0$, so $P_W(v)=0$.

Just want to say a massive thanks for writing this. It’s been bugging me for like a year. Took me ages to even accept that the sum only worked when the vectors were orthogonal (I kept thinking I was making algebra mistakes). First half is amazing, I’ll let you know if I have any questions on the second half!
